# Error response from Razorpay getting empty

Tags: android, payment, production-environment, production, razorpay

I'm using RazorPay sdk 1.6.18 in android mobile app

```
@Override
public void onPaymentError(int code, String response, PaymentData data) {
     try {
         System.out.println("Payment Error");
         String errorMsg = null;
         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
         if(jsonObject.has("error")) {
             JSONObject errorJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject("error");
             if(errorJson.has("description"))
                 errorMsg = errorJson.getString("description");
         }
         Toast.makeText(this, errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } catch(Exception e) {
         FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
     }
}
```

in onPaymentError() String response is getting empty & it's throwing exception

```
org.json.JSONException
End of input at character 0 of
```

We got this issue from crashlytics & it's affecting few users in production.
Does anybody have any clue in which case response will be empty & what's a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Just Try,

Response strings must be checked for empty, null, or "null" status before being assigned a JSON object. then turn the response string into a JSON object. able to prevent crashes